# memory leaks in the lists tokyocabinet

Tags: c, memory-leaks, tokyo-cabinet

Do I to use the function `free()` after the use:

```
TCLIST *list = tcbdbrange();
```

or using enough :

```
tclistdel(list);
```

Do I to `free(p)` for: `p = (lk_key*) tclistval(list,...)` or `tclistdel(list)` delete all elemenst of list ?

Answer (score 3):

Haven't you read any [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcbdb)? These are typical questions that should be answered by the docs. As a matter of fact, they are:

> Because the object of the return value is created with the function '`tclistnew`', it should be deleted with the function '`tclistdel`' when it is no longer in use.

I interpret that to mean that you don't have to iterate over the list and delete each element individually.

Comment: I create code by documentation TCLIST *list = tcbdbrange();... tclistdel(list); but I have leaks...